# View SQL queries executed by eclipse link JPA on weblogic console or log file configured using log4j

Tags: java, logging, eclipselink, log4j2, weblogic12c

I am using eclipseLink  2.5.2 JPA library with weblogic 12.2.1.4.0
I want to view all the sql queries executed by JPA in the weblogic console. I have done the below changes to my persistence.xml and enabled (Redirect stdout logging enabled and Redirect stderr logging enabled):

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST" />
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
```

Still i am not able to view the generated sql in my weblogic console. Please let me know if i have missed any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is telling EclipseLink that the server controls all logging when you specified `<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>`. This means everything is controlled through the WebLogic logging settings, not EclipseLink, and probably why you don't see anything. You will need to check the WebLogic docs on how to make changes within its console.

Otherwise, as per the EclipseLink [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging), you can specify `<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>` to have it use the other EclipseLink property values you've defined and have them logged to the console.